# Is the Generalized Assignment Problem with weights=1 NP-hard?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, np-complete, network-flow

#### Description

The Generalized Assignment Problem consists into assigning an items $i$ to a bins $j$.

If we assign item $i$ to bin $j$ (i.e., $x_{ij}=1$) we obtain a profit $p_{ij}$.

Each bin $i$ has its budget $t_i$, and assigning item $i$ to bin $j$ incurs into a cost/weight $w_{ij}$.

The goal is to maximize the overall profit without exhausting the bins' budget:
\begin{align}
\text{maximize } & \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} x_{ij}. \\
\text{subject to } & \sum_{j=1}^n w_{ij} x_{ij} \le t_i & & i=1, \ldots, m; \\
& \sum_{i=1}^m x_{ij} = 1 & & j=1, \ldots, n; \\
& x_{ij} \in \{0,1\} & & i=1, \ldots, m, \quad j=1, \ldots, n;
\end{align}

#### Question

This problem is known to be NP-hard.

Is it still NP-hard if the cost/weight is constant, e.g., $w_{ij}=1,\ \forall i,j$?

Comment: Which are the items and which are the bins? In the first two paragraphs the first index $\ i\ $ of $\ x_{ij}\ $ is said to represent an item and the second to represent a bin, but in the third paragraph $\ i\ $ has suddenly switched to representing a bin. In any case, according to  the abstract of [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300309010078?via%3Dihub), cited by Wikipedia, the  problem is NP-hard.

Answer (score 2):

With $w_{ij}=1$, the problem reduces to a *transportation problem*, which has several  polynomial-time algorithms.